# How to modify a firebase ref value in the scope of a defered promise

Tags: angularjs, firebase, promise, angularfire, restangular

I have a simple chat system using Firebase and AngularFire.

- I want to add some user metadata to every message viewed by a user.
- The metadata comes from an Api using a promises based client ( Restangular ), and the metadata is also tied to the message, so the metadata is addded to the message once the response comes from the api.
- I want to do this everytime a new message arrives.
- If the user comes late to the conversation and have a X message history not viewed, i want to do this for each message.

I'm struggling with the architecture, and i know I'm doing it very wrong. I'm messing with the scope, etc..

**The problem is that the metadata is getting added sometimes to the wrong message due to having a wrong message key.**

Any help will be very appreciated.

---

Here some code commented, in order to illustrate the problem.

Firebase reference of messages sample:

```
  test
    -JeMIr3b7O4HLQTutPUO
      content: "Hi my friend, how are you"
      created_by: "John"
      metadata
        maria: "Liked the message, Cloudy Wheather 90 degrees, with a happy mood, and viewed on monday"
        peter: "Disliked the message, Sunny Wheather 180 degrees, with a sadd modd, and viewed on freiday "
    -JeMIwh7VrNaz_eVaPhe 
      ...
    -JeMIzg9UrAzU8QXW-ze
      ...
    -JeMRORvKTOLul5Ib6_l
    -JeMROyOXHTz6eEs3zVq
    -JeMRPNOByT5PavObwnS
```

Here a sample of the code:

```
.controller('RoomCtrl', function($scope, $window, $stateParams, $firebase, $state, Restangular, settings, Auth) {

  $scope.messagesRef = new Firebase('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/rooms/' + $stateParams.slug);
  $scope.messagesObj = $firebase($scope.messagesRef.limitToLast(30)).$asArray();
  $scope.current_user = Auth.current_user;

  //Get all the values in order to check if metadata was added 
  $scope.messagesRef.on( "value", function(snapshot) {

    var messages = snapshot.val();

    angular.forEach(messages, function(message, key) {
      // If metada for the current user is not added let's added!
      if( message.translations[$scope.current_user] == undefined){
        $scope.addMetadata(message, key);
      }
    });

  });

  //Add the metadata to very new incoming message
  $scope.messagesRef.on( "child_added", function(snapshot) {

    var message = snapshot.val();
    var key = snapshot.key();

      // If metada for the current user is not added let's added!
    if( message.metadata[$scope.current_user] == undefined){
      $scope.addMetadata(message, key);
    }

    scrollBottom();

  });


  // THE PROBLEM
  $scope.addMetadata = function(message, key){

    $scope.current_user = settings.get("name");

    // Scope messing! 
    $scope.key = key;

    //Calling a metadata api based on my user and the message 
    Restangular.all("/").customGET("metada", {name: $scope.current_user, message: message}).then(function(response){

      // THIS executes defered ( pomises ) 
      // and if i don't mess with the scope i don't realy know the key related to the message I want to modify
      // The problem is that sometimes the KEY here is not the key of the proper message due to the paralell execution of this
      // addMetadata function when iterating on the messagesObj
      var key = $scope.key;

      var metasObj = $scope.messagesRef.child(key).child("metadata").child($scope.current_user);
      metasObj.set(response);

    });

  }


}
```

Comment: Why is `var metasObj` defined but not used? Should the following line be `metasObj.set(response);`?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Roamer-1888 , I did a wrong transcription of my code.

Comment: `$scope.key` looks wrong. You should be able to rely on `key` in the closure formed by `$scope.addMetadata(message, key)` {...}.  Moreover, `$scope.addMetadata() = function ...` also looks wrong. This could be a straightforward inner funtion - `function addMetadata(message, key) {...}`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the problem with using ```key```in the closure formed by the function is that then on the restangular promise resolution ```key```is not available. That's why I'm saving ```key``` in ```$scope.key```.

Comment: If it's just a question of executing ` $scope.messagesRef.child(key)...`, then there's no need to involve `$scope`. In fact, involving `$scope` is unreliable. `$scope.key` could be overwritten by the time the async Restagular response arrives.